# Embed JVM into micro-controller

Tags: java, jvm, embedded, microcontroller

I am new in embedded world. May be I am wrong. But I want a relevant solution.

I just want to embed java environment into a MCU for ease to develop application. The MCU vendor have provide the C library for lcd, sensor, spi, buttons, UART, DIO etc etc. Can I embed java into this ?? I mean, I want to use java on the MCU, uppon those device drivers.

Can I use or make something like this??

I have seen the simple [Real-Time-Java](http://www.rtjcom.com) it's very tiny.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be thinking of Java ME (micro-edition) which designed for embedded systems.

Comment: What kind of microcontroller? 8 or 32 bit, how much flash and RAM?

Comment: 32 bit RISC, with 128kb rom & 128 kb ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at **[NanoVM](http://www.harbaum.org/till/nanovm/index.shtml)** and **[Bajos](http://code.google.com/p/bajos/)**.